# Terraform version error when deploying to AWS through jenkins?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, terraform

I was deploying using terraform through Jenkins *Terraform v0.10.7*.
After a success deployment from my local machine using *Terraform v0.11.1*, I can not do it again from Jenkins, I have this error :

```
Terraform doesn't allow running any operations against a state
that was written by a future Terraform version. The state is
reporting it is written by Terraform '0.11.1'.
```

Comment: The error message looks pretty clear to me: Terraform won't allow you to run older versions of Terraform against state files that are newer than it to prevent it from corrupting state file or mangling things. Upgrade your Jenkins' Terraform version and also consider setting the Terraform version to use in your code: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/terraform.html#specifying-a-required-terraform-version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Using v0.11.1 run: `$ terraform destroy`
- Remove the `.tfstate` file
- Using v0.10.7 (or any version you want to use from now on), run: `$ terraform apply`

Comment: while destroying resources could be a way but not ideal solution for production infrastructure :)

Comment: I suppose/hope it's not prod, since they are deploying from local machine and using different Terraform versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TFE maybe you can re-queue the previous state created with 0.11.x. Or perhaps you can look in Jenkins history to get the last state created with 0.11.x.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine, Manuel Sierra has bumped into this error and concluded with the following solution: (Be careful with the following, it is going to give version errors if you happen to downgrade to another version incompatible with the code)

In our case, downgrade from `0.11.14` to `0.11.13` yielded no errors.

1. Execute `terraform pull state > current.state`
2. Modify the version with the one executed by you
3. Execute `terraform push state current.state`

Now you are good to go with the downgraded version.